# Uploading multiple files in Django without using django.forms

Tags: python, django, file-upload

So I've created a form that includes the following item

```
<input type="file" name="form_file" multiple/>
```

This tells the browser to allow the user to select multiple files while browsing. The problem I am having is is that when reading / writing the files that are being uploaded, I can only see the last of the files, not all of them. I was pretty sure I've seen this done before, but had no luck searching. Here's generally what my read looks like

```
if request.FILES:
    filename = parent_id + str(random.randrange(0,100))
    output_file = open(settings.PROJECT_PATH + "static/img/inventory/" + filename + ".jpg", "w")
    output_file.write(request.FILES["form_file"].read())
    output_file.close()
```

Now, as you can see I'm not looping through each file, because I've tried a few different ways and can't seem to find the other files (in objects and such)

I added in this `print(request.FILES["form_file"])` and was only getting the last filename, as expected. Is there some trick to get to the other files? Am I stuck with a single file upload? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your file element `form_file`, the value in `request.FILES['form_file']` should be a list of files.  So you can do something like:

```
for upfile in request.FILES.getlist('form_file'):
    filename = upfile.name
    # instead of "filename" specify the full path and filename of your choice here
    fd = open(filename, 'w')
    fd.write(upfile['content'])
    fd.close()
```

Using chunks:

```
for upfile in request.FILES.getlist('form_file'):
    filename = upfile.name
    fd = open(filename, 'w+')  # or 'wb+' for binary file
    for chunk in upfile.chunks():
        fd.write(chunk)
    fd.close()
```

Comment: I tried that, but only got bits of the file, or "chunks" I think they call them in django. It was pretty weird, I had to switch to this method to actually get the entire file. The chunks were 4kb.

Comment: Maybe you can try the recipe for handling chunks mentioned in the docs : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files

Comment: When dealing with chunks, how do I know when I'm finished my first file, and starting my second?

Comment: I've tried that, but upfile is a string no matter what (when I upload a single file, or multiple files) which is why I can't do chunks() on it.

Comment: When I print request.FILES when uploading 1 file: `<MultiValueDict: {u'form_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: n556057924_592062_5411.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>` and when uploading 2 files `<MultiValueDict: {u'form_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: n556057924_839946_4670.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: n556057924_839947_4940.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>`

Comment: This is really strange - that you're seeing upfile as a string.  The printout you pasted shows that FILES is a dictionary, form_file is a key to a list, and the elements of that list are UploadedFile instances.  So I'm at a loss to explain why you see a string ...

Comment: What does it show if, instead of `print request.FILES`, you do: `print request.FILES['form_file'][0]`?  If that doesn't show up as a string, the neither should `upfile`.  (BTW, made a small edit to use the name property for filename, but I don't think this explains your problem.)

Comment: I tried to access [0] and [1], but every time I did that I got `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object does not support indexing`. I guess because it's a string? So weird!

Comment: Also, I am doing these tests with both small and large files (totaling under the 2.5mb limit where it starts chunking, and totaling over to force chunking)

Comment: The difference is I get `'TemporaryUploadedFile' object does not support indexing` when it is over 2.5mb. I assume the different wording is because it is chunked.

Comment: @Shane: try the change I made above to use `request.FILES.getlist` directly.  This should ensure that you're getting a list back (instead of a string or other strange behavior).

Comment: request.FILES.getlist returns `<bound method MultiValueDict.getlist of <MultiValueDict: {u'form_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 100_1717.JPG (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: 100_1718.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>>` but when I try to loop through it I get `'instancemethod' object is not iterable` on both >2.5mb and <2.5mb uploads

Comment: @Shane: you have to specify the argument: `request.FILES.getlist('form_file')`

Comment: Jackpot. Thank you very much for the persistent help!